# How can I use 有点 or 一点 to add "a little" to a verb?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, adverbs

According to [Chinese Language grammar wiki](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Comparing_%22youdian%22_and_%22yidian%22):

> #### Used with Nouns
>
> 一点 (yīdiǎn) can be placed before a noun to mean "small quantity," like 一点水，一点钱 while 有点 (yǒudiǎn) can't be used this way.
>
> #### Used with Adjectives
>
> 有点 (also 有点儿) is placed before an adjective, and it usually expresses something that the speaker doesn't want or his own negative feelings about something.

一点 (also 一点儿) cannot be placed before an adjective. Instead, it is placed after adjectives. The adjectives that can be used are particularly limited. 一点 is often used when comparing, or expressing speaker’s wish or expectation.

However, how can you use these words when you want to use it on verbs? For example, in order to add *a little* to the following sentence:

> 我会说汉语。

Which is the correct adverb and in what position should it be placed?

Comment: in the case of verbs with objects OP provides answer themselves (genderless pronoun), in particular 我会说汉语:我会说一点汉语， there remain intransitive verbs, e.g.
，sleep a little, rest a little, think a little, walk, run, dream, swim, a little, in which case "a little" may mean a short time period, leading to 一会（儿）：睡一会儿，休息一下, , 想好了再说,别信口开河了!Think a little before you go shooting off your mouth!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to say some action "a little bit", you can put "一点儿" or "点儿" after a verb. In your case, you may say:

> 我会说(一)点汉语。

You can see the [here](https://www.chineseboost.com/grammar/yi-dianr-placement/) for other examples.

Answer (score 3):

If asked

> 你会说汉语吗？

On the positive side, you can say:

> 会一点。

or

> 我会一点。

or

> 我会说一点。

or

> 我会说一点汉语。

They are the same meaning.

On the negative side, you can say:

> (我)一点也不会。

These mean you know nothing.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, "我会一点" here means "我会一点汉语", so it's also the way "placed before a noun".

BTW, "有点" sometimes could means "have a little", so, in fact, you can say "有点钱" or "有点水" if you mean you have some money or water. You can judge it as a short form of "有一点".